# Convert .pdf file to a .mobi file.with Images and text as normal text

Tags: pdf, images, conversion, mobi

First of all I should ask all the readers to not to mark this as DUPLICATE without going through the whole content. 
I searched well before posting this, and I found many pdf to mobi question, I think those questions don't have the solution what I need. So I thought of posting again.

I have a pdf format ebook file which is very rich with diagrams. I tried to convert that pdf file to a .mobile file with Calibre and with [this](http://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-pdf) online tool.

But both gave me same output. It converted successfully, but without those diagrams. Non of the diagrams were there in the converted file. Both the files have only text. Text also not proper aligned, also numbering and other attributes were not there properly organized.

When I asked about this from one my friend he created a .mobi file converting each and every page in to an image, That was properly structured, but the file size was bigger and each time when I turn a page I had to zoom. Also as the whole page is an image it doesn't support the magnificient function of Kindle which is dictionary look-up. So it's completely useless. How can I convert my pdf to a .mobi file which having all the diagrams and text as normal text.

How can I success fully convert my file with the requirements given above?
Any help would be really great. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you can link a example PDF (with many diagrams) to play around with. This way, you will get alot better answers

Comment: @nixda Is it ok if I post a torrent file here? I don't think posting a file here would be a GREAT IDEA.

Comment: Your file shouldn't contain personal data (if possible). You can upload and share a PDF via www.ge.tt or any other file uploader.

Comment: @nixda It's a text book. Not having my personal data. Sorry cannot upload anywhere.